# how does a browser know when a video / audio is playing and post the "playing" notice in the title bar?

Tags: javascript, video, browser

[image]

When a media source is playing via an **iframe** from remote locations like Youtube, Vimeo, CNN etc, the browser's title bar shows the play state and allows click to mute at the title bar. What is the coding method that executes the notice?

I looked at a few methods including the following but cannot determine what listener process should exist to get the state, being that the sources are remotely inserted

- `window.navigator.mediaSession`
- `mediaStream()`

What I want to do is set a condition such as this **concept**

```js
const browserNoticePlaying = document.addEventListener("browserNoticeEvent", function(e) {
  if( e.playState === "playing" ) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
});

if( browserNoticePlaying ) {
  $("#container").html("<h3>This is the thing to see</h3>");
}
```

Comment: The audio player is part of the browser. It knows that ithe video is playing because it's playing it. This is like asking how it knows what URL to put in the location bar.

Comment: @Barmar in other words, you don't know how it is done but just needed to boost your response score.

Comment: @Nadal did you really imply that a 732k points person needed some sort of response score boost? Your inability to understand doesn't make the answer wrong. The answer is right, the browser knows how to display the audio data because it runs the file, you want to access the data from a page, page that is rendered by the browser and not the other way around. A page has only access to its content so either get the video element nested in your iframe or create a browser that exposes all tabs to eachother and watch the cookies and personal info get stolen by a simple javascript injection

Comment: If the iframe is in a different domain than your JavaScript, it doesn't have access to any of its elements. So your script can't get the playing state of an embedded video. The browser itself has access to everything, so it can display whatever it wants.